# Problem making queue with actionListeners in my Chess game on Swing

Tags: java, swing

I tried to create queue for two users playing chess.
Problem is that i cant stop method which uses actionListener and reuse it to update pieces on deck.

I created two classes for player and opponent that responds for piece movement on deck.
Both classes have two methods which uses actionListener.
First one is when we click on our current place, where piece at.
Second one is to place out selected piece on possible tile.

Class Player, Method 1.

```
    public void firstPartTurn(){
        for(JButton button : whitePiecesListCreator()){
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        figureRecognition(button);
                        secondPartTurn(button);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

class Player, Method 2.

```
    public void secondPartTurn(JButton button){
        OpponentAction oa = new OpponentAction();
        GamePanel gp = new GamePanel();
        for(JButton secondPlaceButton : gp.getPossibleTilesToGoList()){
            secondPlaceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    piecePlaceSecondPart(secondPlaceButton);
                    button.setIcon(null);
                    gp.getPossibleTilesToGoList().clear();
                    oa.firstPartTurn();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

when Players turn is finished i call method "firstPartTurn()" for opponent.

Class Opponent. Method 1

```
    public void firstPartTurn() {
        for(JButton button : blackPiecesListCreator()){
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    figureRecognition(button);
                    secondPartTurn(button);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

class Oponent, Method 2

```
    public void secondPartTurn(JButton button) {
        PlayerAction pa = new PlayerAction();
        GamePanel gp = new GamePanel();
        for(JButton secondPlaceButton : gp.getPossibleTilesToGoList()){
            secondPlaceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    piecePlaceSecondPart(secondPlaceButton);
                    button.setIcon(null);
                    gp.getPossibleTilesToGoList().clear();
                    pa.firstPartTurn();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

After opponent turn is done it calls player to turn using method firstPartTurn();
So, we should have recurtion.
I expected methods with action listener stop after piece is transefered, and call method from opponent class.

Comment: [mcve] please ..